# Span ID returns empty string when extracting price

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the price from the div ID tag to show when I try to print

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL="https://www.futbin.com/20/player/75/ruud-gullit"
headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.70 Safari/537.36"}
page = requests.get(URL,headers=headers)
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")
title=soup.find(id="Player-card").get_text()
price = soup.find(id="ps-lowest-2").get_text()
print(price)
```

it should show the price of the player but it only returns a "-"

Comment: can you paste the html of the element you are trying to extract this price from?

Comment: Sorry I am new to this, do you mean the link of the website i am trying to get the price from#/

Comment: https://www.futbin.com/20/player/75/ruud-gullit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the page is dynamicly loading the price. So the html you are getting with the scraper is different in you browser because your browser loads the javascript and thus the data and the scraper does not.

Edit:
To go above and beyond for you. I would inspect the network of the site and capture what url is called to get the pricing of the player.
I see the url: https://www.futbin.com/20/playerPrices?player=238434&rids=238433,214100&_=1572009060306 
This will give you a json blob where you can find the price. Play with the arguments to get what you want.

Comment: Is there any way to overcome this?

Comment: I edited my response. You can check the API they are using and use it yourself. Of course they can change this whenever they want so do not count on it too much. If this helps you dont forget to accept the answer.